# How to visualize a SVM using Matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, machine-learning, computer-vision

Is there any way to visualize svm model in Opencv using matplotlib in python like this one http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html .

Answer (score 1):

In order to visualize decision boundary of SVM your data has to be **two dimensional**. If this is a case, you can just use scikit-learns code, and just substitute call to `.predict` with analogous predict from your own library (like opencv).

Comment: Is that why they just took 2 features only??

     X = iris.data[:, :2]

Comment: Yes, they silently modified the problem so it is possible.

Comment: There are many many methods of mapping high-d to 2d,
[Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) --
so many that there's no clear "try this first".
Nonetheless a simple, very rough SVM boundary plotter would be nice.

Comment: @denis you are missing a point here. To plot a boundary you need more than just reducimg a training set to 2d as you want to plot a boundary of model in true space and in order to do so you would have to project whole input space and somehow decide how to plot infinite overlapping points.you cannot reduce training set, train there and plot as it has nothing to do with the original model